# How to stop iPad/Safari from treating certain numbers as 'phone numbers'?

Tags: ipad, contacts, mobile-safari

I've got some pages on an intranet that show numerical rates to 4 decimal places, eg 147.1453. When these pages are viewed on an iPad, some of these rates appear underlined and clicking on them causes the iPad to offer to create a new contact, or add to an existing contact. Clearly it thinks that the text represents a phone number (which it doesn't really, as we're in the UK and phone numbers are not formatted with periods).

Is there a way to stop this happening - either with meta-data we can put in the web pages, or by changing some setting in our iPads?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In the `<head>` of your web pages, add:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
```

There's lots more where this came from at [Apple URL Scheme Reference: Phone Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH6-SW1).

Comment: Just tried this, works a treat. Many thanks! I had a feeling there would be some meta-way to turn this off. :-)

Comment: Here @Dori, take this badge! :P

Comment: that worked for me too, but not on iPod 1st Generation's Safari. Is there any specific tag for that old browser?