# iPhone setting to turn off auto-detection of phone numbers?

Tags: iphone, ios

In Safari and the Notes app on iPhone, wherever there are strings of numbers they get linked and treated as phone numbers.

I'm sure there was a setting to turn this off but I cannot find it. Where is it?

(Note: I'm not asking for how to prevent this happening on web pages as in [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1201/how-to-stop-ipad-safari-from-treating-certain-numbers-as-phone-numbers), just a setting for my phone.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is currently **not** possible to disable the automatic linking for phone numbers, web addresses, and email addresses on iOS 7, and it never has been possible on previous iOS versions.

Answer (score 1):

On iOS, the phone number auto-detection can be disabled on a *per instance basis* by enclosing the number with backticks (backquote, Grave Accent UTF-8 `0x06`).

The following example was tested in a Calendar event note:

```
`55-01234`
```

The backtick `` ` `` can be reached by a press & hold on the single quote `'` of the keyboard.

[image]