# Disable phone number auto-detection on macOS?

Tags: macos, calendar, facetime

Is is possible to disable phone number auto-detection *on macOS*? If yes, then how?

Scenario: I added a *product number* in an Apple Calendar event note. Now, that Calendar note product number, if clicked, tries to make an Apple FaceTime call.

A similar question was asked in 2014, which applied to iOS but not for macOS : [iPhone setting to turn off auto-detection of phone numbers?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/140304/iphone-setting-to-turn-off-auto-detection-of-phone-numbers)

Answer (score 3):

On macOS, the phone number auto-detection can be disabled on a *per instance basis* by enclosing the number with backticks `` ` `` (backquotes, Grave Accent UTF-8 `0x06`). For example:

```
`55-01234`
```

[image]